# Primary decomposition thm proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying the proof of Primary Decomposition Theorem in Linear Algebra, Hoffman and Kunze. Page 221, in the process of proving that minimal polynimial for $T_i$ is $(p_i)^{r_i}$, I don't understand why $g(T_i)=0$ implies $g(T)f_i(T)=0$.

Comment: Move this question to math.stackexchange and you will probably get an answer.

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the post. Volunteer helpers are unlikely to have access to a specific edition of a book and want to spend their time inferring the context of your question.